# What exactly does Panel.IsItemsHost do?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

What is the `Panel.IstItemsHost` attached property used for?

I see plenty of examples of people setting it on the `ItemsContainer` template for an `ItemsControl`, but the un-documentation over at MSDN does not explain why or what advantages setting property confers.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Say I have an ItemsControl.  I want to use a custom panel that swoops items in and out as you scroll; its called a SwoopPanel.  Now, how do I tell the ItemsControl to use my SwoopPanel to contain the templates it creates?

The quick way is to set the ItemsPanel on the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <lol:SwoopPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

However, sometimes that doesn't work for you.  Maybe you wish to customize how the SwoopPanel is presented in the UI, and the only way to get around this is to change the control template of the ItemsControl.  Now you can add your SwoopPanel directly to the control template and, using the property, mark it as the ItemsHost that the ItemsControl will put all the templated items it creates.

```
<Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Border CornerRadius="5">
          <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <lol:SwoopPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Do you have to do it one way or the other?  No.  Is one more advantageous than the other?  Well, the second way allows you more control of the UI, the first way is easier.  Take your pick, really.  I've never personally done it the second way, but I think there might be a couple of places where it might be useful.

Comment: So basically, the ItemsControl code will make note of the control being set as IsItemsHost in it's hierarchy, and if no ItemsPanelTemplate is set, use that child as the container for the generated children?  (I guess it's possible it might throw if you have a template AND an IsItemsHost child).

Comment: IsItemsHost is not an attached property

Comment: @kai thanks updated.  Seems like a good candidate; feels a little odd that Panel knows how ItemsControl is implemented.

Comment: I agree. Off the top of my head I thought that was an AP as well. Then I realize its syntax is not AP.

Comment: I believe you can set any dp on any object; they are just implemented as a map in the static instance of the DP mapping this-ptrs to values.

Comment: Mentioned in this 2005 Avalon blog: "How do I change the layout of an ItemsControl?" http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=10

Comment: Oh man.  This is a life saver.  No more ItemsPanelTemplate!  Well not for now anyways.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand. Because there is a `ItemsPresenter` and MSDN says:  
_Used within the template of an item control to specify the place in the control’s visual tree where the ItemsPanel defined by the ItemsControl is to be added._  
So why would we want to use items panel directly in ControlTemplate?
[System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Robot1que Because you're changing the template of the control, and within this template you define the items presenter.  What's confusing about this?

Comment: Another reason for using `IsItemsHost="True"` rather than `ItemsPresenter` is that you can access it as a [template part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This, while correct, is a little misleading.  You can still customize how your panel is presented in the control template without having to embed it directly.  Again, that's precisely what `ItemsPresenter` is used for.  The decision is really do you want to make it easy for consumers of your control to replace the panel. If so, use the ItemsPresenter which lets them set the ItemsPanel property. If not, embed the panel directly and set IsItemsHost=true on it in which case ItemsPanel is ignored.  But in both cases, you can display/customize your panel any way you want.

Answer (score 20):

### More Explanation, Please!

While all of the above answers are technically correct, I feel they don't illustrate how `IsItemsPanel` correlates to the `ControlTemplate` and the presence (or absence) of an `ItemsPresenter` and the corresponding `ItemsPanel` property which it uses.  This answer will attempt to shed light on those things and hopefully clarify when you should, or shouldn't use each.

### ItemsControls, Panels and IsItemsHost, Oh my!

An `ItemsControl` is simply a control that displays a collection of items. It does this by first generating individual containers* to represent the items visually, then it hands those containers over to a specific panel to be laid out for display on screen. As items are added or removed, the `ItemsControl` adds or removes the corresponding containers from the panel as needed.

* *Note: If an item is already an instance of the container type (as determined by the result of the [IsItemItsOwnContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontainer?view=net-5.0) override of the `ItemsControl`)--i.e. you add a `ListBoxItem` instance to the `Items` collection of a `ListBox`--that item is simply passed through as-is directly to the panel, acting as its own container.*

The specific panel used for hosting and laying out the containers is the first one found in the `ItemControl`'s control template that has its `IsItemsHost` property set to 'True'.

There are two ways to specify which panel that is:

1. By inserting an `ItemsPresenter` into the `ControlTemplate` to act as a placeholder for the panel specified by the `ItemsPanel` property. (This is the most common way.)
2. By inserting a `Panel` directly into the `ControlTemplate` and explicitly setting its `IsItemsHost` property to `True`.

But which do you use and why? Read on to find out!

#### ItemsPresenter - "Have It Your Way!"

In a typical `ControlTemplate` for an `ItemsControl` such as a `ListBox`, the template specifies an `ItemsPresenter` somewhere inside of it. Here's a simplified excerpt showing how it's used:

```
<Border x:Name="Bd"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Border>
```

As you can see, there is an `ItemsPresenter` specified inside of a `ScrollViewer` in the middle of the template.  What you don't see however is an actual panel to lay out the items.

So if there's no panel defined in the template, where does it come from?  That's where the `ItemsPanel` property comes in. As its name suggests, this property defines which panel will be used to host and lay out the items.  It doesn't however say where that panel appears in the `ControlTemplate`.

That brings us back to the `ItemsPresenter`.  In short, it's a placeholder that essentially says "When the `ItemsPanel` property is set, I'll insert that panel here and set its `IsItemsHost` to `True` automatically."

> The advantage of using an `ItemsPresenter` in the template for your `ItemsControl` is that you're making it very easy for consumers of your control to replace the panel  ***without having to completely re-template your entire control.***

#### IsItemsHost - "My Way or the Highway!"

However, what if you don't want someone to be able to change out your panel because your control depends on some custom panel implementation and anything else will break the functionality? In that case, you ***don't*** use an `ItemsPresenter` in your template. You instead need to specify the exact panel you want to use.

This is where `IsItemsHost` property comes into play. When set on a panel in the `ControlTemplate`, it tells that `ItemsControl` to use that specific panel to host the generated containers, regardless of what `ItemsPanel` is set to. The `ItemsPanel` property is essentially ignored.

Another benefit of specifying the panel directly in the template is you can then name it and access it just like any other template part.

Here's the same example as above, but rather than an `ItemsPresenter`, it hard-codes a `SpecializedPanel` to lay out the items. We indicate that's the panel we want to use to host the items by setting its `IsItemsHost` property to `True` and finally, we give it a name so we can access it directly from code.

```
<Border x:Name="Bd"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <SpecializedPanel name="PART_MainPanel" IsItemsHost="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Border>
```

In this case, because the template doesn't use an `ItemsPresenter` and instead directly includes a panel with its `IsItemsHost` set to `True`, there is no way for the user to change out that panel short of completely replacing the entire `ControlTemplate`. (As mentioned before, the `ItemsPanel` property is ignored.)

### Bringing it all home...

To recap, if you're a control author and want to give consumers of your control the flexibility to swap out the panel used to lay out your items, then define your template for your `ItemsControl` using an `ItemsPresenter`. Make sure to also set the `ItemsPanel` property in the template to specify a default panel.

If however, want to 'lock' which panel your control uses, then do *not* use an `ItemsPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`. Instead, specify the specific panel you want to use directly in the template, then set its `IsItemsHost` property to `True`.

> Note: There's technically a third scenario, which is arguably more common: You're not a control author creating something to be consumed by other users, but rather are simply re-templating an `ItemsControl` (like say a `ListBox`) for some specialized use in your own application.
>
> In that case, since you are the ultimate consumer of the control, you most likely won't have to worry about other consumers downstream needing to change out the panel, so it's completely fine to simply specify the panel directly in your template (again, setting its `IsItemsHost` true) and not worry about using an `ItemsPresenter` and its associated `ItemsPanel` property as the latter, while valid, would just add unnecessary complexity without any actual benefit.

Hope this clarifies exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 13):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.isitemshost(v=vs.90).aspx

Essentially, what this post says is that if you are replacing the ControlTemplate of a ListBox and want a new layout, set IsItemsHost=true on some panel, e.g. a StackPanel.  Then any items in the ListBox will be automatically added as children of the StackPanel.  If the orientation of the ListBox is Horizontal, then the ListBox will be horizontal.

The other way is to set the ItemsPanel property of the ListBox to an ItemsTemplate and in that template you have a StackPanel. In this case the ListBox items will be added to the StackPanel children just as in the first case.  However, you do not need to set IsItemsHost = true, it will have absolutely no effect.  This is done for you by the fact that you are setting the ItemsPanel property.

Comment: this is the explanation +1

Comment: Almost! :) There's nothing saying you have to use IsItemsHost in a custom ControlTemplate. It's just easier if you do. But you can still use the ItemsPresenter/ItemsPanel combination if say, you're re-styling the chrome around the panel itself, but don't want to affect the ability of others to change that panel.  You can check out my answer for more clarification about how they all correlate.