# Changing ListBox ItemsPanelTemplate has gotten me into trouble?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a `CustomControl` (say `CC`) that has been inherited from `ContentControl` and contains a `ScrollViewer` which includes a `ContentPresenter`. When I put a `ListBox` into the `CC` it works without any problem. But when I set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ListBox` it doesn't notify `CC` to scroll into the `ListBox` selected item.

What's the reason for it? -Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

I'll encounter the problem described above only if I set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` or `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Hidden` and customize the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ListBox` simultaneously. (I need to hide scollbars.)

I wonder if hiding `Scrollbars` prevents `ScrollViewer` contents from notifying it to bring selected item into view, why this issue doesn't happen when I don't change items panel???

---

**Generic.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border ...>
                        <ScrollViewer ...
                            CanContentScroll="True"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"   « PROBLEM
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">    « 

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace1.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:proj="clr-namespace:MyNamespace0;assembly=...">
    <Grid>
        <proj:CustomControl1 x:Name="CC">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>                              «
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>                          «
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>    « PROBLEM
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>                         «
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>                             «

                <!--content goes here-->

            </ListBox>
        </proj:CustomControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: would you show some XAML please?

Comment: Of course! But which part of code do you mean?

Comment: What David meant is can you provide some **reduced** XAML that reproduces this effect?

Comment: Let me see please! I'm working on it...

Comment: I did that for another custom-control, But it works! I'm checking my CustomControl more deeply and will inform you about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the IsItemsHost property for the Panel in the ItemsPanelTemplate to True?

E.g. if the itemspaneltemplate should use a Canvas:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" /> 
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859656/what-exactly-does-panel-isitemshost-do)

Comment: Ok worth the try as that is usually a thing people forget. I guess you then need to provide us with the xaml code to better understand the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel treats its content has having infinite space..
You will have to limit its size explicitly, or change it to other panel, Grid for example.

Try this:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Grid/>  
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Or:

```
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100" Height="100"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Nope! This is already done via placing `CustomControl1` into a grid. (look at MainWindow code.)