# Grouped ComboBox shows group headers, but not items

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, groupstyle

I'm attempting a grouped `ComboBox` using `GroupStyle`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Here the "GroupedItems" property is a `ListCollectionView` with a "GroupDescription" applied.

This almost works: the headers are correct, but the items themselves do not appear in the popup.  Why?

**Note:** I'm using the a modified version of the [`ComboBox` styles/templates on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752094(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the `ComboBox` control template on MSDN is wrong, and the documentation is also wrong.  I realized this after I removed the styles/templates from my resources, and then the grouping showed up correctly.

After extracting the actual built-in control template using Blend, I found that the grouping functionality of the `ComboBox` relies on these named parts: "Popup" (**not** "PART_Popup" as is listed on MSDN), "DropDown", "DropDownBorder", "DropDownScrollViewer", and "ItemsPresenter".

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup">
    <Grid x:Name="DropDown">
        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Thanks <s>Obama!</s> Microsoft!

Comment: From running into the same thing, I can say that the key difference is the `<ItemsPresenter>` element. The ComboBox style provided at the MSDN link in the question hard-codes a `<StackPanel>` as the ItemsPanel (by setting `IsItemsHost=True`). This prevents the `<GroupStyle>` from modifying the panel to display the grouped elements.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54333885/1238851) for a more detailed description.